# 2 black wires, 1 hot and a red wire. Pigtail in outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

I changed out an outdoor light and went to hook up the other one, but the new one didn’t come on when I wired the outside black and white wire. The inside outlet has 2 black wires ( 1 hot ) and a red wire. When I look behind the switch the red wire was only attached and the two black wires weren’t attached. I can’t figure out how to wire it back to make it work

[image]

Comment: What wires were visible at the outside? Any red? Was any black wire outside hot? There are also white wires on the inside box in your photo. It would make sense to me that white from outside was connected to white inside as neutral/return, and that hot black was attached to the switch inside, with the red carrying the switched hot outside.

Comment: Maybe the bare black wire came loose from the switch? Did the outside light work before you started?

Comment: This earlier question seems similar to yours: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/108527/changing-old-light-switch-2-black-wires-and-1-red

Comment: Also note that there are some problems with the wiring in the photo, like the red wire end loop going counter-clockwise rather than clockwise under the screw terminal. There may be issues that are not immediately visible as well.

Comment: Did you wire the new light exactly the same way as you found the old light? Or did you freestyle based on something you saw in the box?  Same question the switch.